# PHP preg_match array and echo the matches out

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I have post with youtube link inside.

So i want to find all matches, replace it with custom link and echo it out.

**This is sample post:

```
  Life is good
 {youtube}NgBZrRCPCH8{/youtube}

 Fun is great!
 {youtube}joRCPCH8{/youtube}

 Earth is round and roll
 {youtube}pwnkfH8{/youtube}**
```

Youtube link is something like json:
   **{youtube}NgBZrRCPCH8{/youtube}**

Something like **youtube.com/NgBZrRCPCH8**

Here is what i have been trying.

```
    $con="Life is good
     {youtube}NgBZrRCPCH8{/youtube}

     Fun is great!
     {youtube}joRCPCH8{/youtube}

     Earth is round and roll
     {youtube}pwnkfH8{/youtube}";

$pattern="/{youtube}/";

$replace="";

$first= preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$con);

$pat="{/youtube}";

$rep="";

$sec=preg_replace($pat,$rep,$first);

$patt="/{}/";

$repl="";

$last=preg_replace($patt,$repl,$sec);

if($last){echo '<div class="vid">
        <div class="vendor">
            <iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$last.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>

      </div>';}
```

THANKS...

Comment: the charater { and } must be escaped to recognition. like \{ and \}

Comment: how you want the output look like

Comment: Something like youtube.com/NgBZrRCPCH8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure what you are trying to do,but as per my understanding i did this

```
$re = '/{youtube}(.*){\/youtube}/m'; 
$str="Life is good
     {youtube}NgBZrRCPCH8{/youtube}

     Fun is great!
     {youtube}joRCPCH8{/youtube}

     Earth is round and roll
     {youtube}pwnkfH8{/youtube}";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

$re = '/([\w ]+)[^a-zA-Z {}]+(?!{)/m'; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches1);

echo '<div class="vid">';
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
    echo '<div class="vendor">
    '.$matches1[0][$key].'
            <iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$value.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

***output***

[image: Videos in output]

Comment: Text inside the post does not display, Is there anything i can tweek to make it display

Comment: +1 for multimedia answer with full coded solution. :) One suggestion: you may want to consider adding a `?` in your `(.*)` because it can eat up multiple tags until the last closing delimiter as in this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nT5eG3) Contrast with this [other demo](http://regex101.com/r/zF7qG8)

Answer (score 0):

An other way:

```
$trans = array ('{youtube}'  => '<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/',
                '{/youtube}' => '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div><div class="vendor">');

$result = '<div class="vid"><div class="vendor">'
        . substr(strtr($str, $trans), 0, -20) . '</div>';
```